# How can I reduce back pain from lifting or holding my child for too long?

Tags: toddler, parents, health, life-skills, pain

I have a 2-year-old son and he is bit heavy. For some months, whenever I carry or lift him, I feel severe back pain.

I've found many sources that claim that this is normal. My doctor also says that this happens normally.

Are there ways to carry a child to minimize backache? Whenever I lift my son, I bend backwards slightly to counter-balance his weight. Can I improve my posture to lessen the back pain?

Comment: Since you have seen a doctor about your back pain, this does not appear to be seeking medical advice, but instead is asking for baby-carrying postures that are less stressful on the back. I've cleaned up the comments and edited the question to clarify its focus.

Answer (score 5):

you may want to try carrying your child in a sling or baby carrier (there are many to chose from at all different price points) instead of holding them. We used this brand successfully https://www.mayawrap.com/ .  Also when picking up a child or anything heavy/awkward make sure you squat instead of bend over at the waist.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Peter, welcome to the site.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Peter, Thanks for your valuable inputs. Will surely take into consideration. Waiting for some more valuable inputs, before accepting any answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Changing baby holding positions is not the only thing you can do to reduce the back pain you are experiencing.  I would also recommend trying to strengthen your back and abdominal muscles.  The easiest way to do this is by doing sit-ups.  You can get information about appropriate exercise regimens from any of many sources:  a physician, a personal trainer, an experienced gym rat, or the Internet.

In the short term, it may be wise to change your carrying posture to rest your child more on your hip, taking more of the weight off your back.  It would also be a good idea to check with a doctor to make sure the back pain isn't caused by an unrelated condition.  Propensity to back pain can be a symptom of a number of other problems, and it would be worth ruling them out.